# How do I access data posted to cakephp api?

Tags: php, post, cakephp-2.3, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to allow a 3rd party to submit Gravity form data to my Cakephp app but not capturing all of the data being sent.

Gravity says it's sending the data under *** Post (Form) ***

I am capturing $_POST, but the post array doesn't contain the posted data, only a description of the posted data. Weird.

Have also tried just capturing $this. $this->input. $this->request etc. There is a lot of data there, but not the form contents.

Is there a global'ish type of variable that is essentially the entire data that is being sent, or a specific way to reference Gravity form data?

I can parse the data, if I can capture it.

At the moment, the data is being json encoded and saved to a file for inspection.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you check $this->request->data ?

Answer (score 0):

I had problem once with $_POST. And i find this solution:

php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially less memory intensive alternative to activating always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

source: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: That actually was the variable I was trying to remember, but it only contains the post array. I'm guessing that the enctype is multipart/form-data. Guessing is the operative word here.